# Are there any websites that have Maqam Based Torah recitation recordings online?

Tags: torah-reading

Similar to the maqam based Quran readings maybe? I always hear people talking about those.

Comment: Most users here are not familiar with what you mean by "[s]imilar to the Quran readings". Can you elaborate so we can find you what you are looking for?

Comment: I’ve seen the Muslims chant the Quran a couple times on YouTube and what not. It’s pretty cool and they have great voices.   Im just looking for a recording of a good recitation of the Torah being chanted in a good tune. Also fast paced preferably.

Comment: https://www.tiktok.com/t/ZPR3cW2Pm/ I found this example by searching it up on TikTok. I don’t agree with what Islam teaches but they sure do know how to chant lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beautiful recordings by parsha of the entire Torah and the Haftarot [here](https://www.karaites.org/torah-audio.html). They are recorded in traditional Egyptian Karaite melodies. Sometimes it sounds a lot like the Muslim call to prayer.

Hazan Rotem Cohen has an amazing voice and the recordings are crystal clear.

He was on Israel's "A Star is Born." More about him [here](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%9F).

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!! This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: The Egyptian Karaite tradition uses a modified form of Sigah like almost all Sepharadim

Answer (score 3):

https://www.vayavinu.com/main-leining-page

This is Rabbi Jeremy Wieder's recording; this is how it sounds when read from a Torah scroll in the synagogue. (In the original Hebrew, with the traditional cantillation, as pronounced by Jews of East European ["Ashkenazic"] ancestry.)

Comment: Note this is Ashkenazi

Answer (score 0):

https://pizmonim.com/section.php?maqam=Pentateuch

Recordings of all of the Torah readings according to the Syrian rite (which indeed has a defined maqam for each week).

Note: The maqam of the week impacts prayers. The Torah is always chanted in the same Maqam style of Sigah (Huzam for Egyptians).